# HTML ArcGIS Online inserting image issue?

Tags: arcgis-online, image, html

Within a story map application I am trying to add a picture to the title. I am adding the picture through HTML code and it works, but for some reason it adds a maximize button to the image.  This maximize button doesn't even work.

How do I remove the maximize button?

[image]

Here is the HTML code?  Here there any thing wrong with it?

```
<IMG src="http://www.healthynorthland.org/media/site_6/images/health_care_setting_80.png">Clinical Care
```

[image]

Thats what the image looks like.  I need to get rid of the maximize button.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is your image is much bigger than the space it sits in, so the browser helpfully allows the image to be resized.

You should be able to get around this by forcing a size on the image, for instance by using the height and width attributes.

like:

```
<image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmz3z.png" width="65" height="56" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Content Type from "Web Page" to "Image".

Comment: That option is for the Main Stage.  The image I am adding is for the title of side panel.